# Python - Merge PDF files with same prefix using PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have multiple PDF files that have different prefixes. I want to merge these pdf files based on the third prefix (third value in the underscore). I want to do this using python library PyPDF2.

For example:

```
0_2021_1_123.pdf
0_2021_1_1234.pdf
0_2021_1_12345.pdf
0_2021_2_123.pdf
0_2021_2_1234.pdf
0_2021_2_12345.pdf
```

Expected outcome

```
1_merged.pdf
2_merged.pdf
```

Here is what i tried but i am getting an error and it is not working. Any help is much appreciated.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import io
import os
files = os.listdir("C:\\test\\raw")
x=0

merger = PdfFileMerger()
for filename in files:
    print(filename.split('_')[2])
    prefix = filename.split('_')[2]
    if filename.split('_')[2] == prefix:
        merger.append(filename)
    merger.write("C:\\test\\result" + prefix + "_merged.pdf")
    merger.close()
```

This is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/test2.py", line 12, in <module>
    merger.append(filename)
  File "C:\py\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 203, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, bookmark, pages, import_bookmarks)
  File "C:\py\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 114, in merge
    fileobj = file(fileobj, 'rb')
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0_2021_564495_12345.pdf'

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir()` only lists filenames; it won't include the directory name.

To get the full path to actually add into the merger, you'll have to `os.path.join()` the root path back in.

However, you'll also need to note that the files you get from `os.listdir()` may not necessarily be in the order you want for your prefixes, so it'd be better to refactor things so you first group things by prefix, then process each prefix group:

```
from collections import defaultdict

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import os

root_path = "C:\\test\\raw"
result_path = "C:\\test\\result"

files_by_prefix = defaultdict(list)
for filename in os.listdir(root_path):
    prefix = filename.split("_")[2]
    files_by_prefix[prefix].append(filename)

for prefix, filenames in files_by_prefix.items():
    result_name = os.path.join(result_path, prefix + "_merged.pdf")
    print(f"Merging {filenames} to {result_name} (prefix {prefix})")
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for filename in sorted(filenames):
        merger.append(os.path.join(root_path, filename))
    merger.write(os.path.join(result_path, f"{prefix}_merged.pdf"))
    merger.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply AKX. I am getting this error, i tired to figure it out but with no luck. Any idea.                             
 prefix = filename.split("_")[2]
IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: You're getting that because some filename doesn't have enough `_`-separated segments. (You might want `if not filename.endswith("pdf"): continue` or similar...)

Comment: Got. Thank you!